# react-native listview some rows not displaying

Tags: listview, reactjs, react-native, react-native-listview

I have a modal with 3 tabs. Each tab has a listview, any dataset larger than 10 rows does not work properly. What happens is on initial load it is displaying correctly. however when more rows are being displayed they are all empty. Not sure what is going on. Using latest React-Native. Here are a couple of screenshots if it helps.

[image: pic 1][image: pic 2][image: pic 3]

```
 <View style={{flex:1, height: this.state.visibleHeight - 100, width: this.state.visibleWidth }}>
    {
      (this.state.isSubdivisions) ? <Subdivisions model={this.props.model.subdivisions}/>
      : (this.state.isProspects) ? <LandProspects model={this.props.model.landProspects}/>
      : (this.state.isFavorites) ? <Favorites model={this.props.model.favorites}/>
      : null}
</View>
```

Tab

```
class ListLandProspects extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const foo = this.props.model.slice(0,10)
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2})
    this.state = {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(foo),
      deviceHeight: Dimensions.get('window').height,
      deviceWidth: Dimensions.get('window').width
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.model != prevProps.model)
    this._updateLandProspects()
  }

  _updateLandProspects(){
    const clone = this.props.model.slice()
    this.setState({
      dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(clone)
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Row>
        <Col>
          <List>
            <ListView
              style={{ height: this.state.visibleHeight - 100, width: this.state.visibleWidth }}
              enableEmptySections={true}
              initialListSize={10}
              pageSize={10}
              dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
              renderRow={this._renderRow.bind(this)} />
          </List>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    )
  }

  _renderRow(rowData) {
    return (
      <ListItem style={styles.listItem}>
        <View style={styles.rowWrapper}>
          <Row>
            <Col>
              <Text style={styles.labelMain}>{rowData.fullAddress}</Text>
            </Col>
          </Row>
          <Row style={styles.toolbarRow}>
            <View style={styles.toolbarDetail}>
              <TouchableOpacity>
                <Icon
                  name='ios-information-circle'
                  style={{color: colors.blue}}/>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.toolbarMarker}>
              <TouchableOpacity>
                <Icon
                  name='ios-pin'
                  style={{color: colors.green}}/>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.toolbarFavorite}>
              <TouchableOpacity>
                <Icon
                  name={rowData.isFavorite ? 'ios-star' : 'ios-star-outline'}
                  style={{color: colors.orange}}/>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </Row>
        </View>
      </ListItem>
    )
  }
}


ListLandProspects.propTypes = {
  model: React.PropTypes.array
}

export default connect(null, null)(ListLandProspects)
```

Styles

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  label: {
    color: '#000',
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  },
  labelMain: {
    color: '#000',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 15
  },
  rowWrapper: {
    padding: 5,
    paddingLeft: 10,
    paddingRight: 10
  },
  listItem: {
    padding: 0,
    marginLeft: 0,
    paddingLeft: 0,
    borderBottomWidth: 0,
    borderColor: 'transparent'
  },
  toolbarRow: {
    height: 38,
    marginTop: 5,
    backgroundColor: '#f2f2f2'
  },
  toolbarFavorite: {
    position: 'absolute',
    margin: 5,
    left: 110
  },
  toolbarMarker: {
    position: 'absolute',
    margin: 5,
    left: 60
  },
  toolbarDetail: {
    position: 'absolute',
    margin: 5

  }
})
```

Comment: Try removing pageSize={10}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> any dataset larger than 10 rows does not work properly

Almost certainly related to this line:

```
const foo = this.props.model.slice(0,10)
```

**EDIT**:

I think your `componentDidUpdate` is flawed. `this.props.model != prevProps.model` will always be `true`, because you can't compare arrays like that. So `_updateLandProspects` will be called on every update, which will re-set your state and since you have an `initialListSize` of `10` you'll probably never see more than that number since it will cause another render over and over again.

Try changing `initialListSize` to a bigger number and remove the `slice(0, 10)` above and see if it behaves the same as now but with that bigger number. This should show if the problem is with the `componentDidUpdate` flaw or not.

Comment: Actually that should be commented out. I was just testing to see if it would work with just 10 rows. Which it does. It doesnt work when I use full dataset

Comment: @texas697 OK. Updated answer.

Comment: that was it. thanks! do you have a suggestion on how to compare props.model for changes?

Comment: @texas697 Happy to help. I don't have enough context to give a great answer but if it's purely an array comparison I would just use [lodash's `isEqual`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.3#isEqual)

Comment: @texas697 If you keep props immutable and don't modify the prop directly then you don't need lodash isEqual. Change the prop by updating the array to a new object (like you should be doing with setState) and the !== will work because they are different references. If you just do `myArray[0].property = foo;` then !== won't work and you must do a deep check which sucks.

Comment: @Jack Lodash `isEqual` shouldn't be ever needed. see my comment above.

Comment: @MartinMazzaDawson um sure, in a perfect world you're correct, but it's not so I wouldn't exactly say "shouldn't ever"...and just as I said in _my_ comment I didn't have enough context to give a good answer and if it's purely about how to compare arrays then `isEqual` will work.